# Regression expressed as Y given X

Tags: regression, bayesian, conditional-probability

I am trying to marry conditional probabilities with linear regression in my head, and would appreciate someone confirming my understanding.

Let say we have target variable $Y$ and covariate variable $X$, and we can fit data with a simple regression model:

$$
Y=\alpha+\beta X + \sigma \zeta
$$

Where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\sigma$ are constants and $\zeta\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, 1\right)$ is normally distributed random variable.

Treating both $X$ and $Y$ as random, I think the correct expression for the conditional probability of $Y$ given $X=x$ would be (giving it as probability of $Y$ being below some value for concreteness of example):

$$
P\left[Y<y \:|\: X=x\right]=\int^y_{-\infty}\,dY\,\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{Y-\alpha-\beta x}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)
$$

In my understanding this describes, for example, the situation where I wrote all my data-points into a two-column spreadsheet (with $X$ and $Y$) and then randomly choose a row, peek at the value of $X$, and based on that know the probability of $Y<y$.

#### Follow-up

Lets now say I have some prior info on probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ in my distributions: $P_0\left[X\right]$ and $P_0\left[Y\right]$.

I do the following with my two-column spreadsheet. I randomly choose a row, but now I choose from the subset of rows with $Y<y$. As far as I understand, I can then use Bayes theorem to update my prior probability of the of randomly chosen row having $X=x$ to take into account that the row was chosen from $Y<y$ subset.

$$
P\left[X=x\: |\: Y<y\right]=\frac{P\left[Y<y\: | \: X=x\right]\cdot P_0\left(X=x\right)}{P_0[Y<y]}
$$

Where $P_0[Y<y]$ is assumed to be extractable from the known $P_0[Y]$
peek at $Y$ this time

Comment: @Glen_b. Thanks for suggestions. I have corrected it in the question - no attachment to these letters, but I agree that following conventions is a good idea (when one is familiar with them :-)). Does my brain-dump make sense though?